# How can i put download link in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, download

I am working in wordpress.
I don't know how to put download link in wordpress.

Basically my requirement is that, User if click in download link then he able to download source code in zip format from website.

I don't know whether it is  done with plugin or not if it is then give me information about it(plugin).

Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WordPress Download Monitor for adding the download links to the wordpress website.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/download-monitor/

You can use wordpress download manager too

http://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/

Answer (score 0):

hello you can do it easly just go to post and click add media now upload you zip file and attach it to the post user can download from there but if you want to monitor your download you can use this plugin :-

http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2009/11/06/the-best-of-series-download-managers/

Comment: @ Sonu Meena, You added more knowledge in me, actually i don't know about it also.so thanks for saving my time. :)